# Regex - Matching a word

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex which matches a word in a String:

> Miete 920

I want to match the word "Miete".

My regex:

```
price.matches("=[\bMiete\b]")
```

However, it doesn`t work? Pls give me a hint.

Comment: So you want to match any string that contains `Miete`?

Comment: Not knowing what problem you are trying to solve, I would use `if (str.startsWith("Miete"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if some string contains separate word `Miete` you can use

```
price.matches(".*\\bMiete\\b.*");
```

There is no need for `=` in your regex, also `[...]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) not string literal.

Answer (score 2):

I think your regex is wrong. Try with

```
price.matches(".*\\bMiete\\b.*")
```

`.*` -> 0 or more charcters
`\\b` -> word boundary

So this will match any string that has *Miete* surrounded by word boundaries.

EDIT: sorry fixed, I forgot how matching works in Java, I'm more used to Perl :)